# Is there any way to change icon text after clicking on it?

Tags: javascript, react-native, app-router

I want to use a single icon for 2 pages. If I'm on home screen and if I press icon A then it will go to screen A and icon A changes to Icon B. If I press Icon B it goes to Screen B and Icon changes to A.
using react native app router (stack).

Comment: Just change the image src and href attributes during onClick event.

Comment: Thanks for your quick reply. I didn't use onClick as these are not buttons. I have used app-router stack (react-native-router-flux)

Comment: You said you want to navigate between pages on clicking the icon. So you can add an onclick listener to your icon

Comment: <a id="icon_link" href="page 1"><img id="icon" src="icon1.png"></a>

Answer (score 0):

add a state variable say `clicked=false` and change it in the on click function, and based i=on this state value change the icon

what i did

```
renderPasswordAccessory() {
    let { secureTextEntry } = this.state;

    let name = !secureTextEntry ?
      'visibility' : 'visibility-off';

    return (
      <MaterialIcon
        size={20}
        name={name}
        color={TextField.defaultProps.baseColor}
        onPress={this.onAccessoryPress}
        suppressHighlighting
      />
    );
  }
```